# Magento 2.2.4 - Modifying Cache configs via CLI or env.php not working when Opcache Enabled

Tags: magento2, cache

So controlling my cache from command line or modifying `env.php` doesn't seem to work. Going into admin showed them all as disabled. Enabling them however within admin worked fine and shows all enabled from command line, env.php and within admin. Modifying them on command line however does nothing but modify env.php and make you think its enabled. What is going on!?

When i disable my **opcache** the issue stops happening and breaks when I enable. I have to flush my opcache everytime for the changes in the cache to become active but only when configuring cache via CLI or direct changes to `env.php`. Opcache seems to be caching these configs now it seems?

For now I have **blacklisted** `env.php` from **opcache** however am nervous that more issues may arise here as have never had to do this before.

## Steps I have taken

1. `bin/magento cache:status` shows all caches set to 1.
2. Checked `env.php`, this has updated fine
3. Reset **permissions** as per dev docs
4. I can't find any instances of `cacheable="false"` within theme or modules
5. **No errors** show in **logs**
6. Checked **redis** which seems to be working however hard to debug the database being being used.
7. Disabled all **custom modules**.
8. Wanted to **disable theme** however new bug in 2.2.4 is stopping this (have renamed to bak majority of folders within theme for now)
9. Restored a **database backup**
10. ...Asked a question on here.
11. Stuck a bounty on it.

## Cache:enable process

I have tried tracing what is actually going on when i run this command and so far I can see that the following happens:

Defined in `Magento\Backend\Console\Command` which extends `AbstractCacheSetCommand`

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this->setName('cache:enable');
    $this->setDescription('Enables cache type(s)');
    parent::configure();
}
```

This then sets enabled the applicable cache types:

```
$changedTypes = $this->cacheManager->setEnabled($types, $isEnable);
```

A few more steps through classes shows this command does the following:

```
public function setEnabled(array $types, $isEnabled)
{
    $changedStatusTypes = [];
    $isUpdated = false;
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if ($this->cacheState->isEnabled($type) === $isEnabled) { // no need to poke it, if is not going to change
            continue;
        }
        $this->cacheState->setEnabled($type, $isEnabled);
        $isUpdated = true;
        $changedStatusTypes[] = $type;
    }
    if ($isUpdated) {
        $this->cacheState->persist();
    }
    return $changedStatusTypes;
}
```

However the following line leads me too and interface and am unable to determine the exact contents of that method:

```
$this->cacheState->setEnabled($type, $isEnabled);
```

This then runs below code:

```
public function setEnabled($cacheType, $isEnabled)
{
    $this->load();
    $this->statuses[$cacheType] = (int)$isEnabled;
}
```

And as Marius points out the persist function is what actually updates `env.php`.

```
public function persist()
{
    $this->load();
    $this->writer->saveConfig([ConfigFilePool::APP_ENV => [self::CACHE_KEY => $this->statuses]]);
}
```

This all seems to work correctly however will leave here as may help any future debugging. However in my situation `env.php` updates fine and this seems to be where cache configs should be read from, however i have discovered they seem to be cached in **opache** for some reason.

Comment: What does the cache status show in the admin panel, all active or inactive?

Comment: Currently they are all active. It doesn't change if i set them on command line however when i set them from within admin speed of site goes up dramatically so could tell instantly they were actually active. That and i checked with profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up from where you got stuck....
the implementation of the interface `StateInterface` is `Magento\Framework\App\Cache\State`.

method `setEnabled` looks like this:

```
public function setEnabled($cacheType, $isEnabled)
{
    $this->load();
    $this->statuses[$cacheType] = (int)$isEnabled;
}
```

This is in a default install. If you have other custom modules that use a different implementation for the Cache states interface maybe you should look in there.

Moving on to the `persist` method...
It should be in the same class

```
public function persist()
{
    $this->load();
    $this->writer->saveConfig([ConfigFilePool::APP_ENV => [self::CACHE_KEY => $this->statuses]]);
}
```

this is the actual method that should write in `env.php`.

You can easily test if when running the command you reach this method.
(use a simple var_dump, die for test purposes).

If you do not reach this code it means you are using a different implementation for this interface.
And you can check this easily by adding

```
echo get_class($this->cacheState);exit;
```

(or use xdebug and adding a breakpoint)
right before `$this->cacheState->setEnabled($type, $isEnabled);`

Comment: Thanks for your help my env.php does update fine via command line however my cache does not seem to reflect what is in env.php. So does the actual cache configs get set elsewhere do you know? I just commented out that line from the persist method to check that it is in fact being used and yeah env.php did not update.

Comment: what exactly happens? You don't get full page cache at all?

Comment: None of the caches from what I can tell, profiler still shows the whole layout process so layout is not working also (when enabling cache via command line or env.php) It all looks fine and get 0 -> 1 ect and env.php update. Admin however showed them disabled. I'm guessing none are on and so might have to look at the other side of the process which triggers the actual caches state. I thought it just read from env.php. Env.php looks different however now to my other instances since 2.2.4 maybe somethings changed here.

Comment: Yeah so when i have opcache on its causing this strange issue.

Comment: check this for opcache settings: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html

Comment: Yeah ill have a look over that thanks. I added env.php to the opcache blacklist for now which seemed to work hopefully there another config in there that might shed light on issue.